# redirect https to http for content filtering

Tags: https, proxy

Is there a way to create a proxy(proxy a) in the middle so it receives the decrypted https content and send decrypted content via http to proxy b. Proxy b executes the contnet filtering and send it to the end device.

The work flow is like below.

```
webserver--->https--->proxy a---http--->proxy b--->end device
```